# Non tiled and non stretchable background image for UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to create a background image for a UIView that is not stretchable and not tiled?  I want the origin and size of the image to be always the same regardless of the UIView frame size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the contentMode property of your image view.